# Select and output to console the class of the parent div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

How would I output to console the value of the parent div's class? My current code outputs the entire HTML line

i.e if I have this

```
<div class="hello">
   <a id="foo"></a>
</div>
```

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   console.log($(this).parent("div"));
}
```

Why do I keep getting this in my console?

```
<div class="hello">
```

The only thing I want console to show is "hello" (without the quotations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.attr()`

```
console.log($(this).parent("div").attr("class"));
```

https://api.jquery.com/attr/